# Validate model ajax from server not working

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

```
     var Model=  Backbone.Model.extend({
                url: "server.php",
                name:'sasha',
                time:'now',
                validate:function(attrs, options) {

     if (attrs.rand >2) {
      console.log('stop');
      debugger;
    }
                 }
            })

            var model=new Model;



model.on("invalid", function(model, error) {
  console.log('invalid');
  debugger
});

   setInterval(function(){         
      model.fetch();
     model.save()
  },4000
);
```

I want to filter the data that come from the server.
I server I have :

```
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'time' =>date('h:m:s'),rand=>rand()*9);

echo json_encode($arr);
```

No errors in firebug!

Comment: Stop adding the language/tag in the title, especially with square brackets in the end which are used to indicate closed questions.

Comment: so ...what are the syndromes? does "not working" mean you are getting errors? or it doesn't work at all? according to backbone's documentation: "If the attributes are valid, don't return anything from validate; if they are invalid, return an error of your choosing. "  In your case, you are not returning anything in your validate method, thus your model is always valid.